# Rails mountable engine: class can't be called using variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

The following in a private controller method:

```
@commentable = params[:commentable].classify.constantize.find(commentable_id)
```

Gives me an error:

`uninitialized constant Question`

While doing the following (hard coding the class name):

```
@commentable = Question.find(commentable_id)
```

Works just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@commentable = "MyEngine::#{params[:commentable].classify}".constantize.find(commentable_id)
```

Apparently you have to create a string with your engine name in it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing this, and it seems like the only thing that causes this particular error is if there's leading/trailing whitespace contained in `params[:commentable]`. Try stripping the whitespace before classifying it:

```
@commentable = params[:commentable].strip.classify.constantize.find(commentable_id)
```

Comment: It's not a white space. Using strip reproduces this same error. I have a feeling it's probably due to the app being a mountable engine.

Comment: That might be the issue. In vanilla Rails, a whitespace would cause this error – it took a bit of trickery to figure out, since the error message is indicative of a successful model lookup.

Comment: It's very strange -- since hard coding the class works as normal. And using this in a dummy normal rails app works. Something's needed for rails mountable engines.